# How to efficiently convert an Android Bitmap to a Leptonica Pix?

Tags: android, bitmap, tess-two, leptonica

I'm trying to convert a Bitmap to a Pix. However, manually reading every pixel from the Bitmap and setting it in the Pix is too slow.

```
Pix pix = new Pix(width, height, depth);
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        pix.setPixel(x, y, bmp.getPixel(x, y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution in the tess-two repo in [`ReadFile`](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/leptonica/android/ReadFile.java)

It is as easy as:
`Pix pix = ReadFile.readBitmap(bmp);`